# removing a div using jquery for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

Hopefully this isn't a repeat of another question out there.

I want to remove a floating social button sharer when my screen resolution is below a certain number of pixels or a mobile device.

Main reason is so it doesn't load and slow down my mobile page speed on google page speed.

I have entered the following code in my head

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var screen = $(window)
        if (window.innerWidth < 1280) {
            $("#legacy-social-bar").remove();
        }
    } else {
        $("#legacy-social-bar").show();
    }
    });

    //run on document load and on window resize
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //on load
        hideDiv();
        //on resize
        $(window).resize(function() {
            hideDiv();
        });
    });
</script>
```

any idea where I am going wrong?

the div id and class is #legacy-social-bar

Thanks

Comment: I think code you have posted has some kind off a syntax problem.

Comment: Are you trying to hide the div? `$("#legacy-social-bar").hide();`???

Comment: Hi Rejith. I want to remove it as it's slowing down the mobile version of my site. I have another social plugin for the mobile verison.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than remove the div, you may want to hide it instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var screen = $(window)
    if (screen.innerWidth < 1280) {
        $("#legacy-social-bar").hide();
    } else {
        $("#legacy-social-bar").show();
    }
});
```

Also, your brackets on your if else seem to be off a bit.

Comment: Thanks. Hiding it still loads the code and slows the page down as far as I am aware? I'm already hiding it with CSS..

Answer (score 0):

Your if else block is closed prematurely, you have an extra `}`.

Your `screen` variable appears to be unused, you can use the innerWidth from that instead:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var screen = $(window);
        if (screen.innerWidth() < 1280) {
            $("#legacy-social-bar").remove();            
        } else {
           $("#legacy-social-bar").show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks - doesn't seem to be working here; http://www.twinkleclean.co/services/end-of-tenancy-cleaning/ . The code still shows up in the HTML when I reize the screen and reload it... Is it because the code for the resizing screen is missing.,,